# ( Azure logic apps ): How do I obtain the Access Token from Authorized apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a Box Connector I've setup in Azure Logic Apps. Since the Box connector does not support all Box API calls, I would like to write my own HTTP call for the unsupported APIs.
I want to access the Access Token saved in the Connector.
Does anyone know what parameter the access token is stored under?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to get credentials from an API connection. Credentials are stored internally but my guess is Azure wont let you retrieve it.

Comment: What a bummer... Thanks for the info though!